# Can't readout ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I deliver a ArrayList to another method, where I just wanna readout a specific String of the list.

```
public void pruefeWerHat(ArrayList<Teilnehmer> test){

        System.out.println(test);
```

I get this in LogCat

> "1 PeterPan 0 0, 2 Hansi 0 0"

now I just want to use the name, but if I say (after sysout)

> String name = test.get(1);

the problem he said to is, that he cannot convert from Teilnehmer to String. I also tested Teilnehmer.get(1) but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: have you tried String name = test.get(1).toString(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

System.out.println(test);

the toString() method is automatically used. This method is in the Object class, so all objects in java can call this method.

When you do

String name = test.get(1);

the toString() method is not called on it's own, you have to call it yourself. To do this, simply use

String name = test.get(1).toString();

Also, if you want to change what is printed, you can overwrite the toString() method in your class.

```
@Overwrite
public String toString() {
    String stringToPrint = "This string will be printed";
    return stringToPrint;
}
```

Now when you do

System.out.println(test);

instead of seeing "1 PeterPan 0 0, 2 Hansi 0 0" you will see "This string will be printed" (or whatever you choose to add in your toString() implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When you print test toString function is called so use this in your code

```
String name = test.get(1).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get(int index)` method available to `ArrayList` returns type `E`. In this instance, it returns type `Teilnehmer`, which is obviously not a String. You can try and cast `Teilnehmer` (although probably not desirable) to String or simply call the `.toString()` method (e.g; test.get(1).toString()) inherited from type `Object`. Or, if desired, calling a method that returns a String. test.get(1).getNameAsString();

The reason you are allowed to call the type in System.out.println(Teilnehmer) is that println makes a call to the object's string representation:

```
 public void println(Object x) {
      String s = String.valueOf(x);
          synchronized (this) {
              print(s);
              newLine();
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the members of Teilnehmer?

You need to use something like

string name = (Teilnehmer)test[1].Name

where Name is the field you are trying to extract